# What are possible implementations of Haskell's type classes and what are their (dis)advantages?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, functional-programming, compilers, type-systems

As far as I know, a Haskell function with type classes constraints is internally compiled to a function with additional arguments that receive dictionaries with the necessary implementations of each particular type class.

- Are there any other possibilities how compile type classes?
- If so, what are their (dis)advantages?
- And what compilers use them?

Comment: There's quite a bit of literature on the subject. Maybe start with _Implementing Type Classes_ by J. Peterson, M. Jones. You could also look at _Type Classes as Objects and Implicits_ by Oliveira et al, which talks about this in the context of Scala, but has quite a large section on related work.

Comment: I found a link to the paper: [Implementing Type Classes. John Peterson and Mark P. Jones](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/pldi93.html).

Comment: @MartinBerger make this an answer ?

Comment: The other one can be found [here](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf).

Comment: @Suresh Venkat, I didn't want to make it an answer because I am not sure these two are the best, or even good answers. It's been a while since I looked at implementations of functional languages. Maybe some of the resident FP bods can chime in.

Answer (score 8):

JHC uses a different approach.  The compiler's intermediate language is a dependently typed lambda-calculus where there is no distinction between types and values.  JHC therefore can perform a case analysis on the type parameter of a function and call the correct overloaded function directly.

The JHC [website](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/jhc.shtml) goes into some depth on the implementation, as well as its advantages over the standard dictionary passing implementation.